# net/sf/json-lib folder not getting created inside Users/.m2/repository

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have the json-lib dependency(as below) in my pom-thin.xml. But still I dont see the json-lib folders getting generated inside my repository/net/sf/... location. Below is the dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
        <version>jdk15</version>
        <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I also tried changing the version from jdk15 to jdk2.3. but it doesnt help.

Answer (score 0):

json-lib did not generated because jdk15 version does not appear in Maven central repository or your Maven manager. You can see versions that you can use in this [link](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22net.sf.json-lib%22%20AND%20a%3A%22json-lib%22). Thus, you should use below dependency instead.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```